# Reloading new data into a 5 starts rating system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rating-system

I have an autoload_process.php file where I retrieve info from my data base and I print it. One of the info I retrieve and print is the rating. I also have in this file my script to print the rating.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('span.stars').stars();
});

$.fn.stars = function() {
return $(this).each(function() {
$(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
});
}
</script>

    //Provide the group that is going to be load
    $group_number = filter_var($_POST["group_no"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    // To show 3 results at a time
    $items_per_group = 3;

    //get current starting point of records
    $position = ($group_number * $items_per_group);
    $city = filter_var($_POST["nameofcity"]);

    //Limit our results within a specified range.
    $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM menu where city='$city' ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT $items_per_group OFFSET $position";
    $rating = $myrow[rating];
    echo '<span class="stars">'; 
    echo $rating;
    echo '</span>';
```

When the page is load for the first time everything works fine but the problem I have is that when I scroll all the way to the bottom and the page is reload with the new info the rating changes. It seams that everytime that a new set of data is loaded all the previous ratings are set to the Maximum or default value "5 Starts" (I'm guessing because the autoload.process.php file is run it again)

**Example:** (let's say that I load 3 results at a time)

**First Load:**

```
Hotel 1 -->  Rating 5  (This is correct)    
Hotel 2 -->  Rating 4  (This is correct)    
Hotel 3 -->  Rating 3  (This is correct)
```

Now I get to the bottom of the page and the next info is loaded (**second load**):

```
Hotel 1 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 2 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 3 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 4 -->  Rating 2  (This is correct)    
Hotel 5 -->  Rating 1  (This is correct)    
Hotel 6 -->  Rating 3  (This is correct)
```

Now I get to the bottom of the page and the next info is loaded (**third load**):

```
Hotel 1 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 2 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 3 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 4 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 5 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 6 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 7 -->  Rating 3  (This is correct)    
Hotel 8 -->  Rating 2  (This is correct)    
Hotel 9 -->  Rating 1  (This is correct)
```

I think the issue is having this piece of code in the audtoload_process.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('span.stars').stars();
});

$.fn.stars = function() {
  return $(this).each(function() {
  $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5,parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
});
}
</script>
```

Especially in this line of code:

```
$(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5,parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
```

Also If I change the value in: Math.min(5,parseFloat  from 5 to 1, when the new  data loads, the previous values change to 1 instead of 5. Like:
**First Load:**

```
Hotel 1 -->  Rating 5  (This is correct)    
Hotel 2 -->  Rating 4  (This is correct)    
Hotel 3 -->  Rating 3  (This is correct)
```

Now I get to the bottom of the page and the next info is loaded (**second load**):

```
Hotel 1 -->  Rating 1  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 2 -->  Rating 1  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 3 -->  Rating 1  (This is INCORRECT) filled with default value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 4 -->  Rating 2  (This is correct)    
Hotel 5 -->  Rating 1  (This is correct)    
Hotel 6 -->  Rating 3  (This is correct)
```

But if I don't include it there then the starts are not fill up and I see something like:(starts without being filled with the value in top of the starts)

[image]

This is what I see if I include the code (Which is what I suppose to see) but then I'm having the issue mentioned above.

[image]

Definition of the class Start:

```
<style>
span.stars, span.stars span {
display: block;
background: url(stars.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
width: 80px;
height: 16px;
}
span.stars span {
background-position: 0 0;
}
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE**

This is what I see before to scroll down and autoload the new data. (As can be observed, the starts are fill up to the same value that indicated in the top of the picture.

[image]

This is after getting to the bottom of the page and doing the autoload. As it can be appreciated the the rating is still the same (3.11 and 2.89) in the top of the picture, so the actual value of the rating didn't change. All the other data associated didn't change either (as for example the number of ratings: 7 and 12) However, the only thing that it changes is the starts being fill up to max=5 and that's why I'm suspecting the issue is in this line of code

```
     $(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5,parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
```

Or just having the script in the autoload_process.php file but I don't know how to solve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are selecting all `<span>` elements each time you run your function, so your math is getting performed on both the newly added items as well as the old ones.

You could use an additional class name to identify spans that need updated. Then do your selection based off of that class.

Maybe something like this would work:

```
echo '<span class="stars notReadyYet">'; 
echo $rating;
echo '</span>';
```

.

```
$.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).html($('.notReadyYet').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5,parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
        $(this).removeClass('notReadyYet'); //remove this class so it doesn't get processed again!
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm avoiding to load all the values everytime with my query  `$query = "SELECT * FROM menu where city='$city' ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT $items_per_group OFFSET $position";`  in fact If I do `echo 'This is the raging ' .$rating;`  to see the value on the scree, the value is correct, but the starts are fill to 5. Please see update on my original post with an screen shoot. Thank you

Comment: I'm not saying your are loading the items more than once. That part appears to be fine.  

I'm saying that once the SQL query is complete and you add the item to the page, your function is acting on all the items on the page, not just the new ones.  

I'm suspecting that `$('<span />')` is grabbing all of them, but you only want to perform that function on the new ones, so you need a way to select only the new ones in your javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I tried your suggestion and this is what happens: First load--> Loads correctly, Second Load --> none of the starts appear. I also tried by using your suggestion on the $.fn.starts function and  `<span class="stars">` in the php code and then: First load --> loads correctly, Second Load --> loads all the starts in blank.    In both cases, now the error extend to all the items. With my original code the error only happens to the items that were previously loaded but not the items loaded in the last load (last 5 items) Thank you again

Comment: Can you share a link to the live page?  Just the HTML obviously.. :-)

Comment: I don't have a live page. I'm working with in on my computer running it with Apache. However, here you can find the code of a simulation of the problem [link](https://sites.google.com/site/ratingsystemexample/home)  . I have also included in the link a video of the problem. Hope this helps. Thank you so Much !!!!!!!!